# problems with extract relevant element from list using Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am a beginner with Python. I recently learned using loops and want to further improve my skills on it.

However, when I try to execute a for loop, the loop returns nothing. The loop itself is trying to extract any element that contains more than 2es, which should return Steven and De Gea.

```
all_data = [['John','Steven','Mosh'],
           ['Juan','Mata','De Gea']]

names = []

for y in all_data:
    if y.count("e")>=2:
        names.append(y)
names
```

Could someone kindly point out where I did wrong, much appreciate it.

Comment: You could check what's `y` after the for-loop statement, by `print y`.  Hint. It's a list.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the reply. I tried with y only, and it returned ['John', 'Steven', 'Mosh'] ['Juan', 'Mata', 'De Gea'], which is a list.

Comment: your y is a list, what you wanna do is iterate it as well. then add the string that match your condition to names. check my answer for the same.

Comment: Thank you Akshay, that really solves my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your loop is iterating over a `list of lists` and not a `flat list`.

This means that in your for loop, `y` takes the value of a `list`. **Printing y makes it clear**. What you want to do is to `iterate over y again` to do check if the condition is met and add the same string to `names`.

```
for y in all_data:
    print(y)           #<--------
    if y.count("e")>=2:
        names.append(y)
```

```
['John', 'Steven', 'Mosh'] #<-------
['Juan', 'Mata', 'De Gea'] #<------
```

A working solution (with clearer variable naming) would be -

```
all_data = [['John','Steven','Mosh'],
           ['Juan','Mata','De Gea']]

names = []

for sublist in all_data:
    for string in sublist:
        if string.count("e")>=2:
            names.append(string)
names
```

```
['Steven', 'De Gea']
```

---

Here is a one-liner list comprehension for the same. Ill let you figure out how this is exactly the same as the above nested loop :) -

```
[string for sublist in all_data for string in sublist if string.count("e")>=2]
```

```
['Steven', 'De Gea']
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
all_data = [['John','Steven','Mosh'],
           ['Juan','Mata','De Gea']]

names = []

for y in all_data:
    for x in y:
        if x.count("e")>=2:
            names.append(x)
names
```

To find out why your code doesn't work try `print('y')` in your for loop to see what y iterates over.

Your code example would work if your array was `all_data = [['John','Steven','Mosh', 'Juan','Mata','De Gea']` .

Comment: Please check your code before post... It's not working.

Comment: Tested the code, but instead of copying I wrote it again to use ''proper'' variable names and forgot to change one variable. Code now working